# cURL: Bad username/public key combination

Tags: curl, ssh, ssh-keygen

I want to establish an SFTP connection. Until now I just sent my public RSA key to the partner. If the key was added to the `authorized_keys` file everything was fine. But now I got the following error message from `curl`:

```
* SSH public key authentication failed: Invalid signature for supplied public key, or bad username/public key combination
```

The partner said they wanted an "open rsa ssh2 key". So I created one with this command and gave it to them:

```
ssh-keygen -e -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub > ~/.ssh/id_rsa_ssh2.pub
```

Now if I use the original public key I get the same error message like above. When using the new SSH2 key I get:

```
* SSH public key authentication failed: Invalid key data, not base64 encoded
```

So clearly I don't understand what I am doing. Can anyone enlight me?